# CSS: Importing custom font-styles in a single font-family

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I'd like to use a certain font which comes in different styles/weights for bold, italic etc. on my projects. The different styles should belong to one specific font-family "share".

So I came up with this CSS:

```
font-face {
font-family: 'share';
src: url('share-regular.eot');
src: url('share-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('share-regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('share-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('share-regular.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'share';
src: url('share-bold.eot');
src: url('share-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('share-bold.woff') format('woff'),
     url('share-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('share-bold.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'share';
src: url('share-italic.eot');
src: url('share-italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('share-italic.woff') format('woff'),
     url('share-italic.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('share-italic.svg') format('svg');
font-style: italic;
}
```

(There's also a monospaced variant, but i put that into a different family "share-mono" for now.)

But this doesn't work for "italic". I'm not sure about "bold": It looks ok, but it could be that it's just the "regular" being boldened and not the specific share-bold being used.

So I'd like to know if it's even possible to achieve what I'd like to do, and if so, where's my mistake?

Thanks in advance!
Hendrik

Comment: In what way doesn't it work for italic? If the italic face can't be loaded, the browser will take the upright version and slant it; is that what happens?

Comment: Also, is this a font that's available somewhere? Or that you can upload somewhere we can take a look at it?

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for your reply! I know that italic doesn't work, because I see a slanted regular "f" in my test page rather than the "nice one" which comes with italic eof/woff/ttf.

The font files are hosted on a subdomain. Maybe I'm having CORS issues? Check http://armselig.net/dev/tmpl/. This is one of the templates where the error occurs.

Comment: @MrLister I've just noticed: When I look at the source of http://armselig.net/dev/tmpl/ in the browser and click on the CSS in head, it shows an outdated version... now I'm really confused.

Comment: You mean that http://armselig.net/dev/tmpl/css/style.css is not the correct stylesheet? Hm. There is another stylesheet, at http://armselig.net/style.css which seems to try to include the "share" font, but that one doesn't work; the imported css file don't exist.

Comment: It is the correct file, but not the current version. I see different versions when opening the file directly and when clicking through from the page's source view.

Comment: I somehow fixed the issue by moving the font files from the subdomain to the main domain. Seems that Chrome and Firefox are kinda bitchy about loading webfonts from different domains - no matter how I configure CORS. *sigh*